# Verificar se utilizador existe

Tags: linux, bash

Como posso em *bash* verificar se um utilizador existe, mas de forma a que o *script* funcione em múltiplos sistemas ?

Um exemplo limitado:

```
grep <username> /etc/passwd
```

Não funciona em sistemas que usam [NIS](http://www.linux-nis.org/) ou [LDAP](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/) para gerir os utilizadores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comando [`getent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html) deverá funcionar neste caso.

```
getent passwd <usuario>
```

O comando `getent` exibe entradas de bancos de dados suportados pelo [*Service Switch libraries*](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Name-Service-Switch.html), que são configuradas no arquivo `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Uma outra alternativa que pode funcionar neste caso, é verificar se o *ID* do usuário é válido através do comando [`id`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/id), usando com a opção `-u`:

```
if id -u "usuario" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "Utilizador existe"
else
        echo "O utilizador especificado não existe"
fi
```

Comment: Acabei por resolver o problema com o comando `id` que para já parece ser compatível com múltiplos sistemas de gestão de utilizadores.